# The use of the distance function for finding the end points of an ellipse

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

This is a reference to this question: [Converting a rotated ellipse in parametric form to cartesian form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1204131/converting-a-rotated-ellipse-in-parametric-form-to-cartesian-form).

In the answer, it is posted that to find the extreme points of an ellipse, the distance function:

$$R_1(t) = x^2(t) + y^2(t)$$

should be maximised.

My question is that why not instead:

$$R_2(t) = \sqrt{x^2(t) + y^2(t)}$$

So does this imply that maximizing $R_1(t)$ gives the same result as $R_2(t)$? And if so why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $R_1(t)$ and $R_2(t)$ are both always non-negative,
and $R_1(t) = (R_2(t))^2.$

Also note that if $a > b > 0$, then $a^2 > b^2 > 0$.
Conversely, if $a > 0$, $b > 0$, and $a^2 > b^2$, then $a > b > 0$.

So if you find $t_1$ such that $R_1(t_1) \geq R_1(t)$
for all values of $t$,
then $R_2(t_1) \geq R_2(t)$ for all values of $t$.
Likewise, if you find $t_2$ such that $R_2(t_2) \geq R_2(t)$
for all $t$,
then $R_1(t_2) \geq R_1(t)$ for all $t$.

So a maximum of  $x^2(t) + y^2(t)$ is also a maximum of
$\sqrt{x^2(t) + y^2(t)}$, and vice versa.
But of the two expressions, $x^2(t) + y^2(t)$ is easier to work with.